# Rendering a Block Region in My Custom Theme

Tags: blocks, theming

I am having my custom theme. In the theme.info i have a region latest defined

```
regions[latest] = Latest
```

How do i print that region in my theme? Is the below code correct?

```
<?php print render($latest);?>
```

I tried dragging the Recent Posts block to this, but nothing appears. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear your theme cache to see your custom regions working: http://drupal.org/node/337176

Also see this link to review if something more is missing in your process: [How-to create custom regions in a theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme)