# Add a unique Banner Image to each page

Tags: 7, theming

I've been teaching myself Drupal 7 for the past 2 weeks. So far, I've gotten the general idea, and figured out how to use Views (i think) but it's the most difficult CMS I've ever had to learn and I've pulled out lots of hair.

The problem I'm stuck on now is that I want to be able to let the site administrators attach a unique banner image that will appear at the top of every page in my theme. There is a 'banner' region in the theme that was intended to hold this image. I've added a banner image field to the Basic Page content type.  But now I can't figure out how to get that image to show up in the banner region and not in the flow of the rest of the page content (body).

I've tried a few things with views and blocks, but nothing works.  Please Help!

Comment: Just in case the above is unclear.... I want to set a unique banner on each page.  An 'about' banner for the About page. A 'Contact' banner for the 'Contact' page, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method is pretty similar to what Shoaid Nawaz has said above. For Drupal 7, you can use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. Coupled with a custom theme region, you can create a block using the views module which will show an image for each node from a custom image field specified for the content type. You need to have a basic working knowledge of the Views module.

Here is how:

- Create a [custom theme region](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme), name it something like "Banner Region"
- In your content type, add an image field, name it something like "Banner image". If you need description, enable Alt tags for the image field. If you do not need slideshow, restrict the number of image to 1. For slideshow, you can use the views_slideshow module.
- To create similar sized banner images, you can create a new image style.
- Create a new View. Name it something like "Banner". Choose "block" display and not "page".
- In the filter criteria, choose your content type.
- Add a contextual filter for "Content: Nid" and save the view.
- Now go to the your blocks administration page and add the newly created views block to your new banner region.

In short:

- Banner image is a new image field in an existing content type.
- Views module understands which image is attached with which node using the contextual filter.

Tip: You might want to disable this block on the frontpage if your frontpage is not a node.

Further tip: You might consider adding other content types to the filter criteria if you banners for multiple content types. Alternatively, you can create a block for each content type and block control visibility using "No results behaviour" in the views' settings.

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll give it a try and update how it turned out. Thanks.

Comment: Doing this, I realized I tried this early yesterday morning, but I couldn't figure out how to connect the individual content items to the page (Nid) it needs to display on. Also, in my Filter Criteria I have the following options from the Content type I created: field_banner_image:alt, field_banner_image:fid, field_banner_image:title.   I'm not sure which to pick or exactly what's happening by picking this.

Comment: @Ben I agree connecting the nodes to their respective images is the trick here. Try keeping the filter criteria simple. Add only Content: Published (Yes) and Content: Type (= Page). Then add the contextual filter: Content: Nid. The thing should not be more complex than this.

Comment: Have a look at this [screenshot](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/4413/selection012.png). This is the view I had created. Note that the view preview won't show any result. You won't get any result until you put the block on a page.

Comment: this sort of worked.  it's showing the default image that I told the content type to use, and has a pager that maxes out at 26 pages for some reason.  I still don't see how it makes the connection that one particular banner should be shown on one particular page.

Comment: Did you configure your image field to accept only one value? In Views, make the pager to display all items. The connection between node and image is done through the contextual link. The view basically shows the image which is attached to the node presently being viewed. Since you have added an image field to a node, the images are treated as attachments of that node. Views uses this contextual filter to get the node id and searches for images that are attached to this node id. When you provide only one value, the view will find only one image and show it in the banner region.

Comment: So in your example is the image it's own content type or an added field of the page content type?  If it is it's own content type, then how does the "About Us" banner know to only show on the "About Us" page, and not the "Contact Us" page?

Comment: I have it limited to 1 (plus the default)

Comment: @Ben As I had specified in my original answer, it is an added field to an existing content type. So the images become attachments for nodes, but they do not themselves become a separate node. Thus, "About Us" page will add the contextual filter of Content:nid (which is the node id) to find the image attached to that node and display it on the About Us page.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now.  When you first said, "In your content type, add an image field..." my brain said, "Create a content type that has an image field."  I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it turns out. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I will suggest you to redo it from the beginning. Remember two basic things: banner image is a new image field in an existing content type. Views module understands which image is attached with which node using the contextual filter.

Comment: Success!! I had to remove the View, like you suggested, but after I did that and set it up correctly, it worked. At first it was showing every banner image on every page. I fixed that by setting the Contextual Filter > content: Nid to the option to "provide default value with type of Content ID from URL".

Comment: Glad to know it worked, @Ben. That is precisely what the contextual filter is for.

Comment: I know this Post is quite old, I had the same requirement for a drupal 8 project, here is some additional information:
-> when you set the Content: Node ID, select "Provide Default Value" and "Content ID from URL"
-> Make sure you really set the filter containing the Content Types that really have the Banner Image you want to display! Otherwise the View will break!
-> Create a Custom Block, that contains a Fallback Picture and add it to the no result section

Comment: @KaustavDasModak: i follow your instructions but my image is not shown on banner region.

Comment: For add the region in the template. i added this regions[banner_image]    = Banner Image to .info file and     <?php
    print render($page['banner_image']);
     ?> the above code is page.tpl file

Answer (score 1):

There is [Header Image](http://drupal.org/project/headerimage), a module but unfortunately not for Drupal 7. I do not think if you can port it yourself.

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/1146866) is another guide for alternate purpose.

Comment: I've actually seen that page.  It makes sense, but it's not really manageable on a site that has more than a few pages. There must be a "Drupal" way to get this done that doesn't require placing potentially hundreds of individual blocks in the right regions.

Comment: Yes Header Image is right choice in this regard, as I am using it but not in your case. :(

Comment: Try this module in your dev site and test it carefully. This is D7 port of Header Image. http://drupal.org/files/headerimage-7.x-.1.0-alpha.tar_.gz

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried to install in drupal 7 and it would not take.

I'm shocked that there's not a way to do this without an additional module.  It's such a common web design practice that I can't see Drupal being so successful if you can't even add a banner image to a page without jumping through hoops and installing alpha modules.

Answer (score 1):

I managed it in a different way in an experiment using Views and content type.

A Content type (Banner) with two additional (Content) fields.

```
1. Image field
2. Visibility Location (URL) field
```

Then I created a view with `block` display type.

Fields:

```
 - Image field (Imagecache output)
```

Filter:

```
 - Node type: Banner
 - Published: True
```

Contextual filter:

```
- Content: Visibility Location
```

I then edited the options under this contextual filer as:

```
1. Select "Provide default value" 
2. then select type as "PHP code"
```

I then added `PHP contextual filter code` as under

```
if(drupal_is_front_page()){
  return '<front>';
}else{
  return drupal_lookup_path('alias',$_GET['q']);
}
```

**TEST:**
I put the views block in header region and created two nodes of banner types

- For node 1 I selected *`Visibility Location`* as `<front>`
- For node 2 I selected *`Visibility Location`* as `contact-us`

And it worked!

Comment: Thanks. I had to change the Field Type of Visibility Location to Text instead of URL.  Using URL as the Field Type forced the input to be a valid URL (e.g. http://whatever/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's too late to answer this question but I think it will come in handy when upgrading from Drupal 7 to 8 or 9.

You could give this module a try:
[Dynamic Banner](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_banner)

It has been around for a while (since 2010), and seems like the maintainer is committed to make it compatible with Drupal 8 and 9.