# How to create a custom content type region template?

Tags: theming, nodes

I built a sub theme based on Omega's adaptive Alpha theme. I made a content type called "project". For that content type I need to edit what gets displayed on the project detail page. What is the best way to do this?

I currently have a page--type--project.tpl.php file that I can edit, but Ideally I would like to just edit the region, like with using something like region--content--project.tpl.php file or something. Is that possible? I haven't found anything online with modifying a region based on the content type.

Comment: Could you clarify a little, it's not clear what exactly you want to display and in what region. Do you want to display some stuff in a sidebar? Or in the main content area?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to accomplish your goal. I'll point some of them:

**Using template files**

One of them is to add the new region to your current theme and just use the modules suggested by Sohail ([Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) and [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context)) to make the blocks to be shown in the *project* detail page. This means that your current theme will be a new site wide region to be used as you need.

There is some other questions that cover this:

[How do I create custom regions in a theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme)

[Render a custom region inside node template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51244/render-a-custom-region-inside-node-template)

**Using GUI**

Another way to do this is by using the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module. Here goes a summary of the module description:

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files.

You can also use the [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module suite and also the [Panelizer](https://drupal.org/project/panelizer) module to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should theme the node per content type instead of the page. Refer to this article - http://drupal.org/node/17565

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to approach this is using [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) and [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module in omega.