# Drupal 7 module hook_preprocess_page &$vars

Tags: theming

In my module I have verified this function is being called, but when I try to edit `page--golfguide--alias.tpl.php` it doesn't have the variables available.

In module:

```
function dc_branding_preprocess_page(&$vars) 
{
    $vars['branded_header'] = dc_branding_header_contents();
    $vars['branded_footer'] = dc_branding_footer_contents();
}
```

In template.php for theme:

```
function golfguide_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) 
{
    global $user, $is_mobile;
    if (isset($vars['node'])) 
    {
      // If the node type is "blog" the template suggestion will be "page--blog.tpl.php".
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type;

      // If the node id is "33" the template suggestion will be "page--33.tpl.php".
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->nid;    
    }
    //Create page suggestion for first part of url-alias
    $url_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    $parts = explode('/', $url_alias);
    $parts[0] = str_replace('-', '', $parts[0]);
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$parts[0].'__alias'; 

    if($is_mobile)
    {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.$parts[0].'__mobile';  
    }
}
```

In `page--golfguide--alias.tpl.php`

```
<?php print render($page['branded_footer']); ?>
```

NOTHING outputs and the key `branded_footer` does not exist.

Comment: Try setting your vars in golfguide_preprocess_page().

Comment: I need to do this for every theme when the module is enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to render `$page['branded_footer']`, but the module preprocess function is setting `$vars['branded_footer']`, which would be accessible as `$branded_footer` in the template file.

`$page['branded_footer']` would be set if the theme defines a branded_footer region. In that case, you should follow what [How do I create custom regions in a theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme) says.