# Fixing Notice: Undefined variable: content_share in include() (line 39....node.tpl.php)?

Tags: theming

I followed online tutorials and defined a new region in litejazz Drupal 7 theme info file as :

```
regions[content_share] = Content Bottom
```

and exposed the new block using the code below in `node.tpl.php` as :

```
<div class="clearfix clear"></div>
  <?php if (!empty($content['links']['node']['#links']) || !empty($content['links']['comment']['#links']) || !empty($content['links']['blog']['#links'])): ?>
    <div class="links">&raquo; <?php print render($content['links']); ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($content_share): ?> //<<<<<<<<<<<- THIS LINE CAUSES WARNING
  <div>
    <?php print render($content_share); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($content['comments'] && ($page)) { ?>
    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
  <?php }; ?>
```

Now my logs are getting filled with following warning :

> Notice: Undefined variable: content_share in include() (line 39 of
>   /srv/bindings/ertr88c9reretrea25f7b405eeee/code/sites/all/themes/litejazz/templates/node.tpl.php).

I had tried clearing cache as suggested in other solutions but none worked.

Answer (score 2):

Regions are only available in page.tpl.php, not node.tpl.php.

In page.tpl.php you can use

```
print render($page['content_share']);
```

Comment: The above outputs the region correctly for me but with the warning. I am not a drupal dev, what would be the correct code block for the above implementation?

Comment: You won't get the warning using the above code (unless you're getting a different warning, about an undefined array index). Have you left `print $content_share;` in a template file somewhere?

Comment: @MyPalDrupal In these cases, put the blame on the Drupal cache; most of the times, you are sure to be right. `:)`

Comment: No, here are the relevant files : http://pastebin.com/2jabpa0F , http://pastebin.com/hcQSDptq and http://pastebin.com/bMbTjt2M

Comment: In node.tpl.php you still have `<?php if ($content_share): ?>`. `$content_share` is not available in that context, so you get the warning

Comment: And you still even have `<?php print render($content_share); ?>` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the region is available in the scope before assigning any value to it.

Check with get_defined_vars() in the node.tpl.php

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Same issue is well explained in this [thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-do-i-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme)

Comment: It can't be, regions aren't available in node.tpl.php

Comment: Hi Clive,  I am not saying regions are available in node.tpl.php, just saying a good practice before using any variables in an unknown scope.