# How to list user flags in node

Tags: nodes, flags

I have a node that people can flag to indicate their attendance/interest in that node's activity. However, I would like to show a list of users who have flagged a given node on that node's page. While I can find a way to show a user's current flag state or a flag count for that node in a view, I can't find a way to do this for the node representation itself.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/368644

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can relatively easy do that by adding a views contextual filter for the node id (`nid`) with the following configuration:

- *When the filter value **is NOT in** the URL*: `Provide default value -> Content ID From URL`
- *When the filter value **is IN** the URL or a default is provided*: `Specify validation criteria ->` Your CTs list
- *Filter value format*: `Node ID`
- The flag relationship used should be: `by any user`

Of course you can use that view as a block and place it wherever you like.

Comment: How do I get that view/block to show up at a certain entity view? I can't manage to find that. Or will I have to make a desperate template for that node type?

Comment: @ErikDolor you mean on certain pages?

Comment: From an overview of all these node types, if you click on one, it takes you to a view of that particular node. On that page, I would want to show this list of users. Should I change what the overview page links to, and create a view for a single node? Or can I add this view (with the list of flagged users) to a node's display page?

Comment: Yes, you can add this View/block to a node's display page. By creating the View's block, that block will be available at the block's list of Drupal (admin/structure/block) from there you can place it to any region (you may very well be [create your own region] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-do-i-create-custom-regions-in-a-theme) any where in the node's display page) .Lastly from the block's settings you may set any path(s) that this block could appear as well as permissions settings.

Comment: Ah, great, that's something I hadn't figured out yet. Now I just need to figure out how to get the view working, so far no users are showing up... Will come back later once I have time.

Comment: This seems to work if the path would've been `address.com/[node-id]`. However, for my path (`address.com/node/[node-id]`), no results are returned...

Comment: You mean the block settings? Sorry,but I'm not sure there is such a url pattern in Drupal: `address.com/[node-id]`. Regarding the other pattern: `address.com/node/[node-id]`, if we are talking about the block settings, please remove the `address.com`, you don't need the absolute url, just this: `node/[node-id]`.

Answer (score 2):

As said by mchar, it can be done easily using views.

1) Create a view by selecting your content type.

2) Under Relationships in Advanced tab, select Flags (flag name) by any user and (flag)Flags:user
[image]

3) In fields tab, Add user name field and Flag user as relationship.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok, then maybe my actual confusion is different. From an overview of all these node types, if you click on one, it takes you to a view of that particular node. On that page, I would want to show this list of users. Should I change what the overview page links to, and create a view for a single node? Or can I add this view (with the list of flagged users) to a node's display page?